# How to correctly pass credentials to ssh-steps-plugin's `sshCommand` without using string interpolation?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

so I have the following pipeline stage, which works great:

```
stage('Database') {
  steps {
    script {
      remote = createDeployRemote()

      withCredentials([
        usernamePassword(credentialsId: "credential-id", usernameVariable: 'THE_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'THE_PASSWORD')
      ]) {
        sshCommand remote: remote,
          command: """
            somecommand \
              --username="${THE_USERNAME}" \
              --password="${THE_PASSWORD}"
          """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now Jenkins complaints with the following warning:

> Warning: A secret was passed to "sshCommand" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
>
> Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [THE_USERNAME, THE_PASSWORD]
>
> See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.

Of cause I understand that this is insecure, but it seems that `sshCommand` doesn't pass any of the hosts environment variables to the remote machine.

For example I've changed the code to the following:

```
stage('Database') {
  environment {
    THE_CREDS = credentials("credential-id")
  }

  steps {
    script {
      remote = createDeployRemote()

      sshCommand remote: remote,
        command: """
          printenv

          somecommand \
              --username="\$THE_CREDS_USR" \
              --password="\$THE_CREDS_PSW"
        """
    }
  }
}
```

(printenv should print the credential environment variables)

**So the question here is:** is there any way of archiving this without using string interpolation? I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Thanks.

Comment: Upstream issue: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-64552

Comment: See the plugin pipeline doc at https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/ for how to resolve the temporary environment variables within the command instead of within the pipeline where they will be exposed.

Comment: @MattSchuchard yeah I understand this, but when using sshCommand (not simple sh) they are not available.

Comment: In that case, you should probably either remotely invoke the command (i.e. API), or wrap the command inside something locally executed that can perform the SSH (i.e. Ansible).

Comment: While Ansible is a good idea, I don't like that I see every single command getting executed as a single step in BlueOcean then. SO I guess I'll stick with the current less secure solution and wait till the ssh plugin implements something to pass environment variables. *Edit*: thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Have you guys found a solution to this solution?